# can't get youtube iframe and youtube player code to talk to one another

Tags: jquery, youtube, youtube-api

I'm trying to have both an embedded youtube video and some code with the youtube api so that I can create hover events for the video. I'm having trouble, though, linking my iframe with my player code. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong please?

html:

```
<iframe id="playerLibrary" class="playerLocation" width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/YT2ZOD32lWw?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0&enablejsapi=0" enablejsapi="1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

jquery:

```
var tag = document.createElement('script');

  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  var player3;

  function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {

    player3 = new YT.Player('playerLibrary', {
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady,
        //'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
      },
      playerVars: {

      }
    });
}

  function onPlayerReady(event) {
   console.log('ready'); //never fires
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I started working for me when I changed the onReady binding from `onPlayerReady` to `onPlayerReady(event)`.

```js
var tag = document.createElement('script');

  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  var player3;

  function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {

    player3 = new YT.Player('playerLibrary', {
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady(event)
      },
      playerVars: {

      }
    });
}

function onPlayerReady(event) {
 console.log('ready');
}
```

```html
<iframe id="playerLibrary" class="playerLocation" width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/YT2ZOD32lWw?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0&enablejsapi=1" enablejsapi="1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```